# About javascript and DOM, is this standdards-compliant?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<form name='form1'>
   <select name='sel1'></select>
</form>

<script>
   document.form1.sel1 ...  //access element by it's name attribute, is this standard?
</script>
```

Comment: I think you should format better your code and write valid code : use < and >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not specified in [DOM Level 2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) that an HTMLDocument will gain named forms as direct properties, nor that HTMLFormElement will gain named elements as direct properties.

However the behaviour does stretch back to the very earliest implementation of JavaScript (in Netscape 2) and has been copied by every browser since, so it's one of those “DOM Level 0” features that though not formally recognised by any standards body is certainly a *de facto* standard.

I still wouldn't recommend using it, because future browsers may introduce new properties on HTMLDocument and HTMLFormElement (as browsers have regularly done in the past especially on HTMLDocument) whose names may clash with your `name` attributes. This is much, much less likely to happen on the HTMLCollection object used by the `document.forms` and `form.elements` properties.

Better still is to put `id` on anything you want to reference, leave the `name` off `<form>` and use the unambiguous `document.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 5):

The right syntax is :

```
document.forms.form1.elements.sel1
```

or

```
document.forms["form1"].elements["sel1"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do `document.getElementsByName('sel1')`?

> There might be other elements with that name in the same document (e.g. multiple forms containing similar sets of controls) – David Dorward 31 mins ago

Thats why I always use `id` instead of `name`. I'd recommend using either the `forms` array or assigning an `id` to the element for easier retrieval.

Comment: There might be other elements with that name in the same document (e.g. multiple forms containing similar sets of controls)

Comment: If you work off name, then you can reuse the JS between different forms, and just switch in a different form object. :)